# ASP.NET LINQ Database vendors

Tags: asp.net, database, linq

Will Linq work against any database (i.e) MySQL,Sybase,Oracle,DB2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "LINQ".

LINQ to SQL will only work against SQL Server and SQL CE (or whatever it's called these days).

I believe that the Entity Framework (LINQ to Entities) will work with any database supported by ADO.NET... but I *think* that vendors can give more specific support which would no doubt mean better performance and quite possibly a wider range of translatable queries.

Then there are efforts like LINQ to NHibernate which again will work with any ADO.NET-compatible database.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ supports only SQL Server.

However there is a LINQ provider for My sql [here](http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/LINQ-To-MySQL.aspx)

Also, check this [resource](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/e9fc6bc7-fbc6-44c4-b37b-4b4a83beaa3e/) for more info.